# AWT Robot - only taking screenshot of current program on MacOS

Tags: java, awt, screenshot, macos-big-sur, awtrobot

I'm creating a simple test program to take screenshots of the entire screen, after some research, I created the following code:

```
public class PrintScreenCatcher {

    public String capture(){
        try {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
            File file=createTempFilePath();
            ImageIO.write(screenShot, "jpg", file);
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private File createTempFilePath() throws IOException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssS");
        return File.createTempFile("screen-"+LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter),".jpg");
    }
}
```

After run this program, I was expecting a image with my entire screen (MacOS menu, Intellij, etc):

[image: native print screen]

Instead I got a image only containing my desktop's background:

[image: java print screen]

I think robot is trying to take a screenshot only of my program. What should I do to take a screenshot of the opened screens?

Comment: How are you running your code?  Where's the main method?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'm running it throgh junit

Answer (score 2):

The problem was MacOS permission. According with this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/420119), the program **needs permission** to record the screen. I simply added the access to IntelliJ in *System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Privacy -> Screen Recording* and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I added a main method and captured the following image on Windows 10 using Java 14.0.2 with the code compiled to a Java 8 standard.

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the code I ran with.  If you still get a blank screen on Mac, well I can't help you.

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class PrintScreenCatcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new PrintScreenCatcher().capture());
    }

    public String capture() {
        try {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
            File file = createTempFilePath();
            ImageIO.write(screenShot, "jpg", file);
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private File createTempFilePath() throws IOException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssS");
        return File.createTempFile("screen-" + LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter), ".jpg");
    }

}
```